# find number of seconds remaining in a day from current time

Tags: perl, shell

I need to collect vmstat command for a day. But some time I start the command at day time, I want it to finish at 23:59.  what is the best way to calculate remaining seconds in day using shell scipt or perl script?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash:

```
$ echo $(( $(date --date="00:00 next day" +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [DateTime](http://p3rl.org/DateTime) in Perl to do it. Create an object for today with time `00:00:00`, add one day, convert it to epoch seconds and subtract the starting timestamp of your program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DateTime;
print DateTime->today( time_zone => 'local' )->add(days => 1)->epoch - time;
```